# Group and transpose rows in a dataframe based off certain row name

Tags: python, pandas

This question relates to this post here [[Search and return rows underneath in python dataframe and transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170184/search-and-return-rows-underneath-in-python-dataframe-and-transpose][1])

I have a dataframe with text scraped online in each row which contains sports selection information (all in the same column). The solution in the linked post worked perfectly but i have since found more trouble as there is not a consistent pattern in the text. Here is my DF:

```
print(df): 
Col A    

Race 1 - Handicap
14 - NAME
3  - NAME
5  - NAME
6  - NAME
4  - NAME
Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 2 - Sprint
12 - NAME
10 - NAME
8 - NAME
11 - NAME
Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 3 - Sprint
1  - NAME
14 - NAME
8  - NAME
6  - NAME
Race 4 - Handicap
1  - NAME
14 - NAME
8  - NAME
#Race numbers may run up to 15-20
```

This i what im trying to transpose it into:

```
print(df):
Race Name             | Selection No    | Selection    | Race Overview

Race 1 - Handicap     |  1              |  14 - Name   | Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 1 - Handicap     |  2              |  3  - Name   | Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 1 - Handicap     |  3              |  5  - Name   | Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 1 - Handicap     |  4              |  6  - Name   | Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 1 - Handicap     |  5              |  4  - Name   | Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 2 - Sprint       |  1              |  12 - Name   | Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 2 - Sprint       |  2              |  10 - Name   | Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 2 - Sprint       |  3              |  8  - Name   | Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 2 - Sprint       |  4              |  11 - Name   | Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc
Race 3 - Sprint       |  1              |  1  - Name   | 
Race 3 - Sprint       |  2              |  14 - Name   | 
Race 3 - Sprint       |  3              |  8  - Name   | 
Race 3 - Sprint       |  4              |  6  - Name   | 
Race 4 - Sprint       |  1              |  1  - Name   | 
Race 4 - Sprint       |  2              |  14 - Name   | 
Race 4 - Sprint       |  3              |  8  - Name   |
```

This is the function used to transpose IF the pattern was based off a repeating cylcle of 6 lines:

```
df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(data = df['Col A'].values.reshape(-1, 6))
    .set_index([0, 5])
    .stack()
    .rename_axis(index=['Race Name','Race Overview','Selection No'])
    .to_frame('Selection')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Would it be a case of finding the rows between each of the `"Race [0-9] -"` rows and then running the above `df2` for each pattern?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get Race values by pattern
df['Race Name'] = df['Col A'].where(df['Col A'].str.contains('Race [0-9]+ -'))
#get Selection values by pattern - starting numeric of original column
df['Selection'] = df['Col A'].where(df['Col A'].str.contains('^[0-9]+'))
#get info column
df['Race Overview'] = df['Col A'].where(df['Race Name'].isna() & df['Selection'].isna())

#forward and back filling per helper groups
s1 = df['Selection'].isna().cumsum()
s2 = df['Race Overview'].notna().iloc[::-1].cumsum()
df['Race Name'] = df.groupby(s1)['Race Name'].ffill()
df['Race Overview'] = df.groupby(s2)['Race Overview'].bfill()

#remove rows by missing values and also original column
df = df.dropna(subset=['Race Name', 'Selection']).drop('Col A', axis=1)
#added counter
df.insert(1, 'Selection No', df.groupby('Race Name').cumcount().add(1))
```

---

```
print (df)
            Race Name  Selection No  Selection  \
4   Race 1 - Handicap             1  14 - NAME   
5   Race 1 - Handicap             2  3  - NAME   
6   Race 1 - Handicap             3  5  - NAME   
7   Race 1 - Handicap             4  6  - NAME   
8   Race 1 - Handicap             5  4  - NAME   
11    Race 2 - Sprint             1  12 - NAME   
12    Race 2 - Sprint             2  10 - NAME   
13    Race 2 - Sprint             3   8 - NAME   
14    Race 2 - Sprint             4  11 - NAME   
17    Race 3 - Sprint             1  1  - NAME   
18    Race 3 - Sprint             2  14 - NAME   
19    Race 3 - Sprint             3  8  - NAME   
20    Race 3 - Sprint             4  6  - NAME   
22  Race 4 - Handicap             1  1  - NAME   
23  Race 4 - Handicap             2  14 - NAME   
24  Race 4 - Handicap             3  8  - NAME   

                                Race Overview  
4          Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc  
5          Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc  
6          Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc  
7          Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc  
8          Race Overview: lorem ipsum etc etc  
11  Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc  
12  Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc  
13  Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc  
14  Race Overview: Second lorem ipsum etc etc  
17                                        NaN  
18                                        NaN  
19                                        NaN  
20                                        NaN  
22                                        NaN  
23                                        NaN  
24                                        NaN
```

Comment: hi @jezrael. This code is working perfectly although the only thing is it doesnt seem to be picking up "Race 10" onwards. Would i need to adjust the `df['Race Name'] = df['Col A'].where(df['Col A'].str.contains('Race [0-9] -'))` code to capture the Races that go into double figures?

Comment: @SOK - Is possible check `df['Race Name'] = df['Col A'].where(df['Col A'].str.contains('Race [0-9]+ -'))` ? It means one or more digits [0-9]

Comment: Perfect! The + is a handy tip to know so i appreaciate the help @jezrael. Thanks!